# Meteor.setTimeout function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, meteor, settimeout

I've looked around the internet for quite a while trying to figuring out what's wrong with my code and couldn't find a working answer.

```
Template.map.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.options.center,
          map: map.instance
        });
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

I'm simply trying to set a 2 seconds delay for the GoogleMap function to trigger but it doesn't work. I've tried a lot of various things like declaring a var to my function and then trigger the `setTimeout` function anonymously, etc... But no luck... I don't get errors from console so I feel my code is well written and Meteor docs doesn't provide much information on the `setTimeout` function.

This doesn't work as well:

```
Template.map.onRendered(function() {
  Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
    GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.options.center,
        map: map.instance
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Does anything work without the `setTimeout`?

Comment: What are *func* and *delay*? I think you pasted in the syntax of `Meteor.setTimeout` but didn't remove the default arguments. Try `Meteor.setTimeout(function(){...},2000);`  p.s. If you're trying to do something after the dom has rendered you might also look at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush

Comment: @Kyll. Yes, everything's working fine without setTimeout function.

Comment: Instead of putting your ready function inside of map.onCreated try putting `tracker.afterFlush()` inside of `Template.map.onRendered`. You can use `tracker.afterFlush`just like `Meteor.setTimeout` except that it doesn't need a *delay* parameter.

Comment: Well phooey, I'd have to bring it up in the debugger to see.

Comment: @MichelFloyd. Thanks so much. everything you need would be in this article (repo, and sample app) on GitHub.https://github.com/percolatestudio/momentum-iron-router/issues/13

Comment: Seems to be [working in this meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/2wMWrwcfCXi34C4Zk/setTimeout) - Can you fork that example with enough code to repro the issue?

Comment: @KyleMit. This is very weird... I've forked your example with some added code to reproduce the issue but it didn't, now the issue is that the marker will appear only once in a while (on re-navigate, and it doesn't look like it's waiting for 5 seconds). http://meteorpad.com/pad/7sA3LWFthgiBbsWEs/Copy%20of%20setTimeout%20%281%29   I used the EXACT same code on this app deployment (map-bug.meteor.com) but my original issue re-appeared (map stays grey after you've seen it once, try navigating away from it and then re-navigating to it) See repo here: https://github.com/boogieprod/momentum-map-bug

Comment: You're using https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps and following its sample code basically verbatim. Have you tried asking this question as an issue in that repo? I can reproduce the problem but it seems to be either a bug or a missing instruction in the package. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Yes, I've opened the discussion on both packages, no solution so far but thanks anyway for your help, it's appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Take your code inside setTimeout to a external function like this:

```
function prepareMap() {
      GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.options.center,
          map: map.instance
        });
      });
    }
 }
```

And call the function inside the setTimeout **without parenthesis**, like this:

```
Template.map.onCreated(function() {
   setTimeout(prepareMap, 2000);
});
```

If you call the function using parenthesis the function will be executed immediately without the delay specified in the timeOut.

Comment: that is absolutely not how anonymous functions work in javascript. Function definitions are only executed immediately when enclosed in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) such as `(function () {...})()` note the extra brackets on the end denoting execution of the function