# Javascript require returns empty object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to use a library found on the web, called himalaya, which is an html parser.
https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya

I followed their guide on importing the library, so I do

```
var himalaya = require('himalaya');
```

However when I call one of its member functions, I get an error

```
TypeError: himalaya.parse is not a function
```

I tried executing himalaya.parse() on the web browser console directly, it works. I tried commenting out the require statement in the js file, the function no longer works on web browser.

I guess this implies the require statement works? But for some reasons I cannot use it in my javascript file, only on the browser console.

Perhaps something with file scopes? Here is part of my code.

```
var himalaya = require('himalaya');

Template.main.onCreated(function () {
    var http = new HttpGet("www.someurl.com/", "/somedirectories/", function (response) {
        console.log(himalaya.parse(response.content));
    });
    http.sendRequest();
});
```

I am certain that `response.content` does contain a valid html string.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `himalaya.parse` inside the `main.onCreated` function it seems like the library is not completed loaded at that time.  That's why it only runs in your browser console.  Check if the himalaya library has a `onReady` function to let you know exactly when you can use it.   If not, you can:

a) Call the parse function inside the `main.onRendered` or

b) Keep the parse call inside the main.onCreated and set a timeOut to call it after a half second like this:

```
var himalaya = require('himalaya');

    Template.main.onCreated(function () {
        var http = new HttpGet("www.someurl.com/", "/somedirectories/", function (response) {
            setTimeout(function(){himalaya.parse(response.content)},500);
        });
        http.sendRequest();
    });
```

If you have an issue with the setTimeout check this answer:
[Meteor.setTimeout function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947774/meteor-settimeout-function-doesnt-work/43019944#43019944)

Comment: I'm still having the same error. I guess I am not importing the library correctly?

Comment: If the command runs well in your browser's console, try this:  Put a debugger before the parse() line in your code.  When the debugger pause the processing, run the parse command in console, you should have the same issue then in console.  That could confirm that the issue is due async processing.

Comment: I found something strange. On the server console, I find himalaya is undefined. I think due to bad import the library is only available on client side?

Comment: You must define the var in server side then: var himalaya = require('himalaya');